# Can I deny all traffic to a google app engine app from except for traffic from another app engine app from another project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-php

I would like to avoid using the application layer determining wether or not a given web request has originated from my other google app engine app (from another project).

Essentially, only one of my many services needs to be publicly accessible. As such, I was considering placing the publicly accessible service in its own separate project that is open to the public, and placing the rest in another project that would deny all traffic, except for traffic originating from that other project. Is the possible given that I'm not using the flex environment?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to deny all traffic from one App Engine instance in another App Engine instance within another project.

This is due to the fact that App Engine runs on [“a dynamic public IP address of a Google load balancer”](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#private-ip). If this weren’t the issue, you could have used [Serverless VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) as it gives your App Engine standard environment access resources in your VPC network via internal IP addresses.

In your case, I can suggest that you use a Compute Engine Instance to do all the private tasks and have an App Engine Standard app facing the public. You would then set-up the [Serverless VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) in order for the two projects to communicate with each other. This method will work as your Compute Engine will have a private IP address for your app to refer to. This method can also alleviate the need to have multiple projects as you can have your App Engine and your Compute Engine instances on the same project.